Did Jesus write a letter to King Abgar of Edessa?
One gets to read in National Catholic Register, the text of a letter alleged to have been written by Jesus in response to the letter from King Abgar of Edessa requesting the Lord to heal him :

Blessed are you who have believed although you have not seen me. For it is written concerning me that those who have seen me will not believe in me, and that those who have not seen me will themselves believe and shall be saved. But regarding what you wrote me, to come to you, I must fulfill all things for which I was sent, and, after thus fulfilling them, be taken up to Him who sent me. And when I have been taken up, I shall send you one of my disciples to heal your suffering and to give life to you and those with you.”.

I wish to know if the Catholic Church has made any formal study on the said correspondence reported to have been made between King Abgar and Jesus ?

the national catholic register says no Jesus didn't write the letter: https://www.ncregister.com/blog/is-the-legend-true-did-jesus-write-a-letter-to-king-abgar

Is this the letter that starts "A true letter of Jesus Christ" and then ends with something saying that all believers should carry it with them to save them from damnation?  My mother-in-law found a copy of it in an attic somewhere and thought it was real, she sent it to the Bishop to confirm and never heard back.

Thanks, depperm. National Register does not appear to be an official publication of Catholic Church. Hence my specific questions on the stance of the Church. For brevity, I did not use the full text of the question in the title.Please bear with me.

+1 Interesting question. "Saint Abgar" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abgar_V.

Did Jesus write a letter to King Abgar of Edessa?
The short answer is no.
But that does not mean the some Early Church Christians believed in this pius legend. Although a fake, the Abgar Letter was believed to be real by many in the third-century church. The letter even found its way into liturgical use. Today, King Abgar is considered a saint in the Eastern Orthodox Church (with feasts in his honor on May 11 and October 28) and in the Syriac Orthodox Church (with a feast on August 1) and daily in the Mass of the Armenian Apostolic Church.
Many legends, I believe made its way into earlier Catholic Martyrologies, and this one may have been amongst them. However, the Second Vatican Council suppressed anything that resembled pius legends and could not be substantiated by fact. For example, King Abgar has has never been venerated as a saint in the Catholic Church.
Some legends of King Abgar were so popular that they even made it into the Golden Legend! However, such works do not constitute an official endorsement from the Vatican. In fact you will never find such an endorsement, as the pronounced on this subject matter officially. It is obviously fake and untrue.
Jesus never wrote anything while on earth that can be substantiated as real and worthy of belief.
Eusebius seems to have believed in it. Eusebius even claimed that he had transcribed and translated the actual letter in the Syriac chancery documents of the king of Edessa. This records a letter written by King Abgar of Edessa to Jesus, asking him to come cure him of an illness. Jesus replies by letter, saying that when he had completed his earthly mission and ascended to heaven, he would send a disciple (Thaddeus of Edessa) to heal Abgar (and does so).
What individuals are free to believe in does not constitute what the Catholic Church officially endorses. If you want to accept the story as a pius belief you may.
The Letter of King Abgar to Jesus, or the Abgar Letter, is a document written originally in Syriac that purports to be a letter to Jesus and Jesus’ supposed response. The church historian Eusebius, Bishop of Caesarea (c. 260—340), translated the letter into Greek for inclusion in his Historia Ecclesiastica. Through the centuries various legends have sprung up around the Abgar Letter.

The king who supposedly sent the letter to Jesus was Abgar V, king of Edessa. Edessa was the capital of Osroene and a major Mesopotamian city on the northern edge of the Syrian plateau (in what is now southeast Turkey). Edessa is called Urfa today. The letter is rather short. In it, King Abgar tells Jesus that he has heard of the miracles Jesus was performing and asks the Lord to come to Edessa and heal him of a malady. The king also invites Jesus to stay in Edessa, where He would be protected from the animosity of the Jews in Jerusalem. Abgar sent the letter to Jesus by means of a courier named Ananias.
In the reply to the letter from Abgar, Jesus supposedly wrote, “Blessed art thou that hast believed in me, not having seen me,” but then declines to visit Edessa, citing His need to finish His work in Jerusalem. Jesus promised, however, to send a disciple later to heal Abgar. According to the legend, the disciple who healed King Abgar after Jesus’ ascension was Judas Thaddeus, also called Addai, who was one of the 70 (or 72) disciples mentioned in Luke 10:1.
The fact that the biblical record tells us nothing of Jesus’ writing makes any claim that someone has a Jesus-written document suspect. Jesus taught the disciples, and the Holy Spirit aided in remembrance and interpretation, allowing the apostles to deliver the New Testament canon.
The consensus of Bible scholars is that the Letter of King Abgar to Jesus is fraudulent. The document was probably written in the third century AD and then placed where Eusebius would eventually find it. This is not to say that some sort of letter never existed. The question concerns the authorship and date of the letter. It is thought that the basis for the legend surrounding the letter is the Syrian king Abgar IX, who converted to Christianity in the late second century.
What is the Letter of King Abgar to Jesus?

The Catholic Encyclopedia clearly states it is a legend!
